# Visual Studio Code fonts are suddenly different throughout entire application?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

My VSCode fonts have changed throughout the whole app, and I cannot stand it as they are ugly for me.

They look like this:

[image]

I do not understand why this is happening. I am using a Microsoft surface 4 and the default graphics card.

I have tried to edit the settings, but I can't seem to find a solution